# Spark scala join each group in data frame with other reference data frame

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, dataframe

I have the following two data frames. I want do group by on input data frame and join each group with reference data frame on date column.

```
   %>input.show()

  sid|date                 |count
  200|2016-04-30 18:00     | 10
  100|2016-04-30 18:00     | 2
  200 |2016-04-30 21:00    | 5
  100|2016-04-30 21:00     | 4

    %>reference.show()
   id|date           
   1|2016-04-30 18:00  
   2|2016-04-30 21:00  

   expected output
   id|sid|date             |count
   1|200|2016-04-30 18:00  |10
   2|200|2016-04-30 21:00  |5
   1|100|2016-04-30 18:00  |2
   2|100|2016-04-30 21:00  |4
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Plain join:

```
reference.join(input, Array("date"))
```

Comment: thanks!. How to get all the reference rows even though there is no matching row in input data frame.

Comment: thanks!. How to get non-matching rows from reference data frame for all sid(s) from input data frame.

Comment: is this solution really working? can you please add more on Array and grouping column.